# single command to sed and use input value twice in different form

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have file with input values in the form of: `input-prefix:value`.

I need to replace `input-prefix` twice with different substitution and pass it to a command like `my-command replace1-prefix:value replace2-prefix:value`. Is this possible with a single command or do I have to script it?

With one value it's simple

```
cat my-input-file | sed 's/input-prefix/replace1-prefix/' | xargs -r my-command
```

TIA for any assistance,

W.

Answer (score 1):

You can group parts of a pattern with `\(\)` and later refer to it by `\1` (or `\2` ... `\9` if you have more groups in a pattern):

```
s/input-prefix:\(.*\)/replace1-prefix:\1 replace2-prefix:\1/
```

Comment: Don't you have a typo? Hasn't the last `\1` to be replaced by `\2`? In complete: `s/input-prefix:\(.*\)/replace1-prefix:\1 replace2-prefix:\2/`

Comment: Ups, forget about my comment, I should have tested it before ...

Comment: Thanks. I will try to work with it. The only thing is that such sed expression produces single string, which cannot be passed as xargs argument, because `my-command` will then receive one argument with two values separated by a space, not two separate arguments.

Comment: @wciesiel I don't think so. `echo "x" | sed 's/x/file1 file2/' | xargs -r cat` displays both files. I think splitting is performed after the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

It is also simple with multiple values. First, you can skip the cat command in your pipe, due to sed will read from the file and print its output to `STDOUT`. And `sed`works in the way @Philippos described it (and `\1` will be used twice as it belongs to the first capture group). Just remove the echo in the xargs command to run your command. If you want to see the command which was called, you can add the parameter `-t` to see the command or `-p` to perform it interactive. Therefore, you need to state yes/no before running the command.

```
user@pc:/tmp$ cat inputfile.txt 
input-prefix1:value1
input-prefix:value
input-prefix2:value2

user@pc:/tmp$ sed 's/^input-prefix:\(.*\)$/replace1-prefix:\1\nreplace2-prefix:\1/g' inputfile.txt
input-prefix1:value1
replace1-prefix:value
replace2-prefix:value
input-prefix2:value2 

user@pc:/tmp$ sed 's/^input-prefix:\(.*\)$/replace1-prefix:\1\nreplace2-prefix:\1/g' inputfile.txt | xargs -r echo my-command
```

Short note: This assumes, that your input-prefix is the first thing in the line you want to replace and the value is all the rest of the line behind the colon. Also the `g` modifier in the `sed` command will substitute all occurences of your `input-prefix:` within the `inputfile.txt`.